# How to remove Rules which are having errors

Tags: drools

I am having a list of rules created dynamically. Immediately after it is created i check whether there are any errors. But i cannot find a way to remove those rules having errors dynamically.

```
 public void validateRule(List<String> rules, Collection<AbstractFact> facts) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem  kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        int ruleIndex = 0;
        for (String rule : rules) {
            StringBuilder ruleName = new StringBuilder("src/main/resources/rule");
            ruleName.append(ruleIndex).append(".drl");
            kieFileSystem.write(ruleName.toString(), rule);
            ruleIndex ++;
        }
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();

        if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            //Remove rules which are failing 

        }

        KieContainer container = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

        KieSession ksession = container.newKieSession();

        for (AbstractFact fact : facts) { // Insert All the facts
            ksession.insert(fact);
        }
        ksession.fireAllRules();
    }
```

Drools file for validation

```
template header

name

package test;


template "test template"

rule "test rule"

when

    $fact : Fact(code != )  // expression is wrong intentionally

then
    $fact.setOk(false);

end

end template
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issues by compiling the packages first and then using the build packages to load the knowledge package. This way the KieContainer does not fail and simply ignores the rules which are incorrect.

```
public Collection<KiePackage> createAllPackages(List<String> rules) {
        Collection<KiePackage> compiledPackages = new ArrayList<>();
        int ruleIndex = 0;
        for (String rule : rules) {
            StringBuilder ruleName = new StringBuilder("src/main/resources/rule");
            ruleName.append(ruleIndex).append(".drl");
            kieFileSystem.write(ruleName.toString(), rule);
            KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();

            if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
                List<Message> messages = kieBuilder.getResults().getMessages(Message.Level.ERROR);
                continue;
            }
            kieFileSystem.generateAndWritePomXML(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
            KieContainer container = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

            KieBase kBase = container.getKieBase();
            compiledPackages.addAll(kBase.getKiePackages());
            ruleIndex ++;
        }
        return compiledPackages;
    }

    public void buildAllPackages(Collection<KiePackage> packages) {
        KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = kieServices.newKieModuleModel();
        kieFileSystem.writeKModuleXML(kieModuleModel.toXML());
        kieFileSystem.generateAndWritePomXML(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
        KnowledgeBaseImpl kBase = (KnowledgeBaseImpl)kContainer.getKieBase();

        Collection<KnowledgePackage> allPacksTrans = Collections2.transform(packages, new Function<KiePackage, KnowledgePackage>() {
            @Override
            public KnowledgePackage apply(KiePackage kiePackage) {
                return (KnowledgePackage) kiePackage;
            }
        });

        kBase.addKnowledgePackages(allPacksTrans);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write each rule to a KieFileSystem file `try.drl` and call buildAll. Keep track of filing rules.

Delete try.drl.

In a second pass, write as you do now, skipping the rules that failed in the first pass.

Comment: buildAll() always works for me. But the rule fails when newKieContainer is created. For instance the expression of the rule is incorrect. (code != )

Comment: Your comment is incomprehensible for me. Perhaps you add the error messages from the builder to your question, or what else you get as an exception, and stack trace.